# Ionic Cordova Plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, location, tracker

I am new on ionic and I want to track specific location using googlemap, ionic and cordova. For example I'm the user I and want to track the exact location of the ambulance so I can assist the traffic in advance? Is there a way using ionic framework .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`cordova-plugin-googlemaps`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/v/2.3.6)? In the command line:

```
$ cordova create MyMapProject
$ cd MyMapProject
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps \
    --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="..." \
    --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="..."
$ cordova platform add android
$ ...
```